# Can I deploy a RESTful API with .Net Framework 4.5 on AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-4, aws-lambda

I have been trying to anticipate the issues I may face when trying to migrate an existing API developed in .NET framework 4.5 and deployed in an IIS to a serverless architecture based on AWS Lambda.

Currently, the API is divided in: Controller (entry point), service (buz logic) and repository (basically LINQ), and of course some DTO and DAO's, nothing fancy. In addition, I have got some dependencies to external libraries but I don't know if that really matters.

Here is the thing: As I could see when configuring my Lambda, it only accepts .Net Core applications. Ouch! Then, is it necessary to migrate to .Net Core? If it is, can anyone tell me how much development that requires considering my set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is it necessary to migrate to .Net Core?*

**Yes, as Lambda runs on Linux.**

*If it is, can anyone tell me how much development that requires considering my set up?*

You will need to pay specific attention to the dependencies to external libraries, as they need to support .NET core and might add a substantial load time to your lambda function.

If you have an existing .NET API developed in 4.5, **I would strongly advise against trying to migrate the whole API.** Lambda's pay-for-what-you-use model is very attractive, but largely incompatible with ASP.NET MVC/WebApi's server model.

Comment: Is this true for AWS API Gateway too?

Comment: API Gateway is a middleware, so it doesn't run user code. Even when running your code in Lambda, you would still need a middleware (API gateway is most known for this) to accept client requests and do authentication/authorization.